# Slide like Cycle via CSS3

Tags: jquery, css

I have this structure.

HTML:

```
<div id="sequence">
            <img class="prev" src="themes/bc/imagesx/bt-prev.png" alt="Previous" />
            <img class="next" src="themes/bc/imagesx/bt-next.png" alt="Next" />
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="info animate-in">
                        <h2>Built using Sequence.js</h2>
                        <p>The Responsive Slider with Advanced CSS3 Transitions</p>
                    </div>
                    <img class="sky animate-in" src="themes/bc/imagesx/bg-clouds.png" alt="Blue Sky" />
                    <img class="balloon animate-in" src="themes/bc/imagesx/balloon.png" alt="Balloon" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="info">
                        <h2>Creative Control</h2>
                        <p>Create unique sliders using CSS3 transitions -- no jQuery knowledge required!</p>
                    </div>
                    <img class="sky" src="themes/bc/imagesx/bg-clouds2.png" alt="Blue Sky" />
                    <img class="aeroplane" src="themes/bc/imagesx/aeroplane.png" alt="Aeroplane" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="info">
                        <h2>Cutting Edge</h2>
                        <p>Supports modern browsers, old browsers (IE7+), touch devices and responsive designs</p>
                    </div>
                    <img class="sky" src="themes/bc/imagesx/bg-clouds3.png" alt="Blue Sky" />
                    <img class="kite" src="themes/bc/imagesx/kite.png" alt="Kite" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sky {
    width: 100%;
    right: -100%;
    opacity: 1;
    top: auto;
    bottom:-25px;
    vertical-align: middle;

    -webkit-transition-property: left top;
    -moz-transition-property: left top;
    -o-transition-property: left top;
    -ms-transition-property: left top;
    transition-property: left top;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sky.animate-in {
    right: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
    top: auto;
    bottom:-25px;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 4s;
    -o-transition-duration: 4s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 4s;
    transition-duration: 4s;

    -webkit-transition-property: left top;
    -moz-transition-property: left top;
    -o-transition-property: left top;
    -ms-transition-property: left top;
    transition-property: left top;
    z-index: 1;
    ransition-timing-function: ease;
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition-timing-function: ease; /* Opera */

}

.sky.animate-out {
    right: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    top: auto;
    bottom:-25px;

    -webkit-transition-duration: 4s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 4s;
    -o-transition-duration: 4s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 4s;
    transition-duration: 4s;

    -webkit-transition-property: left top;
    -moz-transition-property: left top;
    -o-transition-property: left top;
    -ms-transition-property: left top;
    transition-property: left top;
    z-index: 1;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition-timing-function: ease; /* Opera */
}
```

and i'm using [Sequence JS](http://www.sequencejs.com/) plugin. Everything working. But i want bgclouds and bgclouds2 dont seperate on transition. It's start same time, finish same time. But now, smoothless.

Can i make that structure via CSS3? http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/sliding/ When click image 2, go image1 and directly start image2.

Sorry my hard expression. Please help me.

Comment: Could you port your code to a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: an exemple would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to investigate @keyframes in CSS. These allow you to set the timing for items to start and stop within your animation.